# how to show default dropdown value show top angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a dropdown show below card information and i want to show `is_default= true` card show top other cards below.. please help me

```
<select  ng-model="approvedinvoicesCtrl.currentcard.card_id">
    <option ng-value="item.card_id" ng-repeat="item in approvedinvoicesCtrl.current_job.cards ">{{item.brand +'      '+ item.last_digits}}</option>
</select>


{brand:"Visa",
card_id:"card_19VHhAGdj8iWoXDURuRqNH28",
last_digits : 123123,
is_default:true},
{
brand:"Master",
card_id:"card_19VHhAGdj8iWoXDURuRqNH28",
last_digits : 123123,
is_default:false}
```

Comment: you need to use ngSelected on option element... for more details please see ..... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Comment: I think ng-options directive is a better directive for selectors: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting you with this

```
 <select>
    <option ng-value="item.card_id" ng-repeat="item in dropdownval "
     ng-selected=item._default >
      {{item.brand +' '+ item.last_digits}}</option>
  </select>
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/rqTypEQwwxOXvdXhhPOi?p=preview)

Comment: can you please check the **DEMO**

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar instead of commenting, drop out your answer. Check out the DEMO and do downvote.

Comment: ohh nevermind it has ng-selected..i upvoted..sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: It is not working if I change it to default values https://plnkr.co/edit/1pyYMCboKMJNDvkaXnRm?p=preview

Comment: @AddiKhan when u to get the card_id??

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use [**ngOptions**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) on option element instead of `ng-repeat`.

**Note:** `ngOptions` provides an facility for the "option" element which should be used instead of `ngRepeat` when you want the select model to be bound to a `non-string` value. This is because an option element can only be bound to string values at present. For more information you can check this [**link**](https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs/).

Working demo with **`ngOptions`** **:**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.current_job = {
      "cards": [
        {
          brand:"Visa",
          card_id:"card_19A",
          last_digits : 123123,
          is_default:true
        }, {
          brand:"Master",
          card_id:"card_19B",
          last_digits : 123123,
          is_default:false
        }        
      ]
    };
    
   for (var i in $scope.current_job.cards) {
     if ($scope.current_job.cards[i].is_default == true) {
       $scope.topCard = $scope.current_job.cards[i].card_id;
     }
   } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-options="item.card_id as item.brand+' '+item.last_digits for item in current_job.cards"
   ng-model="topCard"> 
   </select>
</div>
```

Working demo with **`ngRepeat`** **:**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.current_job = {
      "cards": [
        {
          brand:"Visa",
          card_id:"card_19A",
          last_digits : 123123,
          is_default:true
        }, {
          brand:"Master",
          card_id:"card_19B",
          last_digits : 123123,
          is_default:false
        }        
      ]
    }; 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="currentcard.card_id">
    <option ng-value="item.card_id" ng-repeat="item in current_job.cards" ng-selected="item.is_default">{{item.brand +' '+  item.last_digits}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: card_id: ""charge_description: "cc"charge_type: "Credit Card Payment"__proto__: Object

Comment: where you used `ng-click` ?. Don't try to change the original post. I answered as per the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use orderby

```
<select ng-model="approvedinvoicesCtrl.currentcard.card_id><option ng-value="item.card_id" ng-repeat="item in approvedinvoicesCtrl.current_job.cards  | orderBy:'is_default':false">{{item.brand +''+ item.last_digits}}</option></select>
```

Here item 'is_default' property is sorted in a reversed order. The 2nd argument can be any order function, so you can sort in any rule.

@link http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy

Comment: Though this might solve the issue this puts an overhead over performance due to use of filters. Filters are executed once every digest cycle.

Comment: if it lead to digest cycle why should angular introduce orderly filter to dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `ng-init` and the `ng-options` for defaults values like:

```
<select ng-init="somethingHere = options[1]" 
        ng-model="somethingHere" 
        ng-options="option for option in options">
</select>

$scope.options = [
    'Brand1',
    'Brand2',
    'Brand3'        
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer pre-selecting the card (option selected) instead of sorting using the  default card at the top.

You can use the `ng-selected` using the default value if no value is selected in `ng-model` ,  otherwise, it selects the value in ng-model.

```
<select  ng-model="currentCard.selected" >
  <option 
      ng-value="item.card_id" ng-repeat="item in cards" 
      ng-selected="(currentCard.selected==item.card_id) || (!currentCard.selected && item.is_default)">
      {{item.brand +'      '+ item.last_digits}}
  </option>
</select>
```

or you can use the `ng-options` approach. In this last case, you can pre-select an option using the `ng-model` value only.

```
<select 
   ng-model="currentCard.selected" 
   ng-options="item.card_id as item.brand+' '+item.last_digits for item in cards">
</select>
```

See this fiddle with both examples:

https://jsfiddle.net/hdca55cg/

The second one shows default card if you have previously selected in the model.